# May Notes contain emoji graphics?

Tags: contacts

I'm using Civi 5.18.3 on a demo site. I am trying to add the text of a Twitter bio as a new Note for a Contact, and it is not saving. The bio text contains these characters:

```
National Volunteer & Distributed Organizing Manager for
@WorkingFamilies . #WFP4theMany @ http://WFP4theMany.org & http://WFP2020.org RT ≠ endorsement. TEXT WFP TO 738674
```

The User Guide doc page [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/contacts/#notes-tab) does not specify if Notes must be only plain text characters.

Answer (score 3):

There is a patch to support the character encoding necessary: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/339.

The issue is whether to support older character sets for folks who can't/won't switch over.  One position is that it's not a big ask for users to upgrade, but difficult for the developers to support both; the other position is that it forces an update that some folks can't make, or that their database is too big to convert without going offline for several hours.

The "support the new encoding only" patch has been written; this will move forward either when a) someone writes a patch that supports both encodings, or b) folks decide it's OK to force folks to switch.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I did not know that patch existed.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No, Notes (apparently) may not contain emoji graphics.

When I removed the 'megaphone' emoji from the above text, the rest of the Note text saved successfully.